# TypeError: Use async with instead

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

When I run the below snippet, I'm getting `TypeError: Use async with instead`.

```
headers = {'Content-type':'application/json'}
res = requests.post(end_point_recommend, data=json.dumps(dict_query), headers=headers)
print(res.ok)
print(json.dumps(res.json(), indent=2))
NUM = 10
CONCURRENT = 2
VERBOSE = True
payload = {13:5.0, 191:5.0, 209:5.0}
payload_list = [payload]*NUM
%%time
# Run:
with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:  # We create a persistent connection
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    calc_routes = loop.run_until_complete(run_load_test(end_point_recommend, payload_list, session, CONCURRENT, VERBOSE))
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

D:\Anaconda\envs\practise\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py in __enter__(self)
   1068 
   1069     def __enter__(self) -> None:
-> 1070         raise TypeError("Use async with instead")
   1071 
   1072     def __exit__(

TypeError: Use async with instead
```

I'm using aiohttp '3.7.3'. How to resolve this error?

I came across a similar issue in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-cors/issues/184#issuecomment-443495710), but that solution didn't work out for me (i.e on replacing
`with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:`

with
`async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:`,

I get the below error
`SyntaxError: 'async with' outside async function`

**Function Definition of `run_load_test`**

```
def run_load_test(url, payloads, _session, concurrent, verbose):
    http_client = chunked_http_client(num_chunks=concurrent, s=_session)
    
    # http_client returns futures, save all the futures to a list
    tasks = [http_client(url, payload, verbose) for payload in payloads]

    dfs_route = []
    # wait for futures to be ready then iterate over them
    for future in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        data = yield from future
        try:
            dfs_route.append(data)
        except Exception as err:
            print("Error {0}".format(err))
    return dfs_route
```

Comment: https://github.com/andrewsayre/pysmartthings/issues/20

Comment: You need to use async function as mentioned in the above github comment

Comment: If you aren’t using the session outside `run_load_test`, move the `async with` line into it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `async with` must be in an async function. You can modify `run_load_test` to create the session, or you can define a new function that does that, and awaits `run_load_test`:

```
async def run(end_point_recommend, payload_list, concurrency, verbosity):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        return await run_load_test(end_point_recommend, payload_list, session, concurrency, verbosity)
```

At top-level you can call the new function without the session argument:

```
%%time
# Run:
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
calc_routes = loop.run_until_complete(run(end_point_recommend, payload_list, CONCURRENT, VERBOSE))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error
`RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`

Comment: @PurushothamanSrikanth That's a different problem entirely, that should be posted as a separate question.

Comment: I have added the Function definition of `run_load_test` in the question, can you have a look and see what could be done?

Comment: @PurushothamanSrikanth The problem is not in `run_load_test`, it's in the environment you're running the code from (presumably Jupyter). Please ask a separate question about the `RuntimeError` because the answer to your existing question will not apply to the new one.

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
```

to

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
```

Comment: I'm getting this error,
    `SyntaxError: 'async with' outside async function`


As mentioned already in the question.